# Allocating struct objects on heap inside loop in rust

Tags: rust

I need to allocate structs with a drop trait inside a for loop and have a mutable reference for downstream processing. I have created this minimal example code that I can't compile with rust version 1.59. I have tried using the internal mutability with Rc and RefCell as well.

```
use std::cell::RefCell;
use std::rc::Rc;

// MyVec with Drop Trait
struct MyVec {
    vec: Vec<i32>,
}

impl Drop for MyVec {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("Dropping MyVec with data `{:?}`!", self.vec);
    }
}

impl MyVec {
    // Get a mutable slice
    fn mut_slice(&mut self) -> &mut [i32]{
        return &mut self.vec[..]
    }
}

pub fn test() {
    // Needed for downstream purposes
    let mut all_slices = Vec::new();
    // Storing reference counter Rc and RefCell combo
    // Hoping to prevent allocated MyVec objects from dropping and have one mutable reference
    let mut all_refs = Vec::new();
    for _i in 0..1 {
        let my_vec = Rc::new(RefCell::new(MyVec {
            vec: vec![1, 2, 3]
        }));

        // Make a clone of my_vec to prevent it from dropping
        all_refs.push(Rc::clone(&my_vec));
        
        let mut my_vec_mut = my_vec.borrow_mut();
        let x = my_vec_mut.mut_slice();
        all_slices.push(x);
    }

    println!("{:?}", all_slices);
}
```

The same code works when I unroll the loop and write the following code:

```
pub fn test() {
    // Needed for downstream purposes
    let mut all_slices = Vec::new();
    // Storing reference counter Rc and RefCell combo
    // Hoping to prevent allocated MyVec objects from dropping and have one mutable reference
    let mut all_refs = Vec::new();

    let my_vec = Rc::new(RefCell::new(MyVec {
        vec: vec![1, 2, 3]
    }));

    // Make a clone of my_vec to prevent it from dropping
    all_refs.push(Rc::clone(&my_vec));
    
    let mut my_vec_mut = my_vec.borrow_mut();
    let x = my_vec_mut.mut_slice();
    all_slices.push(x);

    println!("{:?}", all_slices);
}
```

**Update:** Thanks to Masklinn's comments, I fixed the code. I needed to create objects in the loop and required a mutable reference to its internal data field outside the scope of the loop. The rust compiler showed an error that the references outlive the object itself. Finally, I used a separate loop to allocate the objects and a second loop with iter_mut to create mutable references. Here is the final code:

```
pub fn test() {
    // Needed for downstream purposes
    let mut all_slices = Vec::new();
    
    // Hoping to prevent allocated MyVec objects from dropping and have one mutable reference
    let mut all_vecs = Vec::new();
    for _i in 0..1 {
        all_vecs.push(MyVec {
            vec: vec![1, 2, 3]
        });
    }
    
    for my_vec in all_vecs.iter_mut() {
        all_slices.push(my_vec.mut_slice());
    }

    println!("{:?}", all_slices);
}
```

Comment: What is the question? Your code doesn't work because borrowing a RefCell returns a guard, and the reference is only valid for the guard's lifetime, since it's dropped at the end of the block the reference is invalid. And `borrow_mut` itself needs a reference to the actuall `RefCell`, which is also only valid until the end of the block. But it's not clear why you're even storing these.

Comment: If you need a `Vec<&mut MyVec>` or an `&[&mut MyVec]`, you can just add all the objects to `all_refs()` then call `all_refs.iter_mut().collect()`: the `IterMut` iterator "knows" that all the items are independent, so it is able to hand out a mutable reference to each.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have updated the post with the problem I needed to solve and a tentative solution. Please suggest if there are any better ways to do it.